# Rails, how to compile only css with webpacker and read the compiled asset from the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm switching from assets pipeline to Webpacker.

I have the amp pages, and in the amp pages with Sprocket I have:

```
- if Rails.application.assets && Rails.application.assets['amp/application']
      %style(amp-custom)
        =Rails.application.assets['amp/application'].to_s.html_safe
    - else
      %style(amp-custom)
        =File.read("#{Rails.root}/public#{stylesheet_path('amp/application', host: nil)}").gsub(/[\"]/,"'")
```

As you know amp pages has inline CSS, and instead of writing CSS I have an SCSS file that is compiled and then inserted in my layout.

I cannot understand with Webpacker how to process my SCSS file.

```
Webpacker.manifest.lookup('amp_pages.js')
```

Return me the path, but I just need the compiled css.
How can I get the path of the compiled pack, and only the CSS?